# How to show beneath posts the full category path?

Tags: posts, categories

My portal has the following category structure:
**CategoryLevel1=>CategoryLevel2=>CategoryLevel3=>CategoryLevel4**

I assign posts to CategoryLevel4 but I want to show the full category path beneath each post. Each node should be clickable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your categories are in a parent=>child hierarchy as listed(ie category4 is a child of category 3, etc) then this should give you what you're after:

```
the_category("&raquo;", "multiple", $post->ID);
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to assign the post only to the child category or the parent AND child category as well?

Comment: If you just assign the post to category 4, it will show links to the parent category 3, ...2, ...1 as well.